# Cpanel: Subdomain redirecting to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: apache-2.2

On my hosting account, I created a new subdomain in cpanel. Let's say, beta.mydomain.com.

When I try to access beta.mydomain.com it works perfectly. However, when I try to access beta.mydomain.com, it redirects me to beta.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

How do I fix this?

Edit:

It appears the .htaccess at the root of the webserver might have something to do with this as well. The rules are as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/beta/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /beta/index\.php [R=302,L]
```

If I type in beta.domain.com/somedirectory, I get redirected to domain.com/beta/index.php because of the rules. How do I exclude beta.domain.com from the above rewrite rules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you visit the subdomain before you added it in cpanel? If so, your browser might be caching the `"<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi"></head><body></body></html>"` bit cpanel serves if you visit an unknown hostname. You could try removing the cache or test it with another browser (or even with wget/curl). 
If apache actually still serves the default html, check if the subdomain is created properly.

Comment: Ok, further to the above edit, you're right - accessing from another computer just redirects me to domain.com/beta/index.php. Can you please help with the .htaccess rules?

Comment: Check HTTP_HOST at [http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Sorry about the late response. You were right, it was a caching issue!

Comment: glad i saw this post before i was going to start looking at and playing with httpd.conf

Comment: I know we shouldn't post thank you comments, but after losing 3 hours of my life, I really have to say thank you!

Comment: How did I forget to test with `wget`!